# PySpark - create pair RDD with two keys that share the same value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a key-value pair RDD where the key is an actor and the value a movie that this actor participates, in the form:

```
["actor 1", "movie 1"]
["actor 1", "movie 2"]
["actor 1", "movie 3"]
...
["actor n", "movie 2"]
```

I want to map this into another key-value pair RDD, where each pair consists of two actors that participate in a common movie.

In the above example, that would mean that the new RDD would contain the pair `["actor 1", "actor n"]`, as they both participate in `"movie 2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple swap and join should do the trick. First lets create some dummy data and a small helper function:

```
actor_movie = sc.parallelize([
    ("actor 1", "movie 1"),
    ("actor 1", "movie 3"),
    ("actor 1", "movie 3"),
    ("actor n", "movie 2")
])

swap = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])
```

Next you swap order:

```
movie_actor =  (actor_movie.map(swap)
    .partitionBy(actor_movie.getNumPartitions())
    .cache())
```

And join:

```
(movie_actor
    .join(movie_actor) # Join by movie
    .values() # Extract values (actors)
    .filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you requested, but I think it is good enough:

```
import itertools as iter

movies = sc.parallelize([("P", "SW4"), ("P", "SW5"), ("P", "SW6"),
                         ("A", "SW4"), ("A", "SW5"),
                         ("B", "SW5"), ("B", "SW6"),
                         ("W", "SW4"),
                         ("X", "SW1"), ("X", "SW7"), ("X", "SW2"), ("X", "SW3"),
                         ("Y", "SW1"), ("Y", "SW7"), ("Y", "SW2"), ("Y", "SW3")])

swap_tuple = lambda (k, v): (v, k)

movies = movies.groupByKey().mapValues(list)

all_pairs = movies.flatMap(lambda (movie, actors): map(lambda actors:(movie, actors), iter.combinations(actors, 2)))

print all_pairs.collect()

""" 
    >> [('SW1', ('X', 'Y')),
        ('SW3', ('X', 'Y')),
        ('SW5', ('P', 'A')),
        ('SW5', ('P', 'B')),
        ('SW5', ('A', 'B')),
        ('SW7', ('X', 'Y')),
        ('SW2', ('X', 'Y')),
        ('SW4', ('P', 'A')),
        ('SW4', ('P', 'W')),
        ('SW4', ('A', 'W')),
        ('SW6', ('P', 'B'))]
"""
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Bonsanto/09a2286cfb1210d3297b) is the run using an `.ipynb`